# one error on memtest test , is it bad?

Tags: memory, memtest86+, memory-error

I have a computer with 2 memory modules, I have run it through a memtest test, and it come up with just one red line that point me to just one Error-Bit.

Based on the fact that currently i am not experience any issues with the computer, but i am want to give it to somebody, and I  don't want him come to me a week after to repair it.

- Is just one error bit bad enough to replace one of the sticks ?
- Is it a sign for more errors to come in the near future ?
- How can i know that the error is because the Memory modules themselves and not from the Motherboard slots ?

BTW: i have done some [search](https://superuser.com/questions/240990/need-help-with-explanation-of-memtest-results) on this [site](https://superuser.com/questions/82299/memtest86-error-explosion-and-then-nothing) in order to find answers to my questions but i didn't found a specific answer for these question.

Comment: Not all *errors* necessarily mean you'll have *problems*.

Answer (score 3):

- Is this ECC memory? If it is, it's fault tolerant to a certain extent. Personally, I'd replace it if it isn't a heat related issue or something that can be cured by reseating the memory in it's slot. The next failure could be on a disk write to an important file.
- Most likely you will see more failures over time, but I would be inclined to make sure it isn't just an overheating or poorly seated memory module.
- To find out if it's a memory module or a slot, swap the memory with a
  stick on another slot and see if the fault location changes.